# Find element using variable in which some text is stored

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

```
var something = row["item_no"];
```

In var something, I am storing item no and now i want to find a row on page which contains this item no which is stored in var something. 
But I want to find a row using variable name i.e. "something".

Comment: what is a row? An array?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Dictionary. I don't know your data type so in example are objects:

```
// your values
var something = "something";
var row = "RowValue";

// store its to dictionary
Dictionary<object, object> myDict = new Dictionary<object, object>();
myDict.Add(something, row);

// and find value by key
var value = myDict["something"]; //value = "RowValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

C# 6 has nice feature `nameof`. It allows you to get variable/property name.


You have mentioned that you want to use variable name, not its value.

So you can use it like this:

```
var something = row["item_no"];
var variableName = nameof(something); //gives you "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    List <string> items= new List<string>();
    items.Add("Item_001");
    items.Add("Item_002");
    items.Add("Item_003");
    items.Add("Item_004");

        string somthing = items[2];

    string item = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToString() == somthing);
    int index = items.IndexOf(item);
    Response.Write("Value found at : "+(index+1).ToString() +" row and value is : "+item);
```